# Cannot Resolve Symbol Content In Android 3.6.1

Tags: android

I have searched many post of related this question here but not found any solution of my issue. That's why I am here.

I have recently updated to Android Studio 3.6.1 and raised the issue of " Cannot Resolve Symbol Content"

my import library is as below:

```
 import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
 import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

above import library not working in Android 3.6.1. how to solve this issue?.  please suggest

Note:- I have tried Several answer related to this post but it is remain unsolved.

I have deleted  Build/ .Gradle and .idea and rebuild the project but not works. I have also tried another solution of this question as below.

1. close the current project
2. remove all the project by X sign
3. Closed the Andoid studio
4. Again restart project by open exist project

but all the efforts are failed. Provide me right solution.

my build.gradle file is as under.

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
          compileSdkVersion 29
          buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

  defaultConfig {
                 applicationId "com.maheshwaghela.mahesh.rukhivivah"
                 minSdkVersion 16
                 targetSdkVersion 29
                 versionCode 1
                 versionName "1.0"

     testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }

  buildTypes {
  release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
        optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
    compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.6
    targetCompatibility = 1.6
}

}

 dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'


 }
```

Comment: can you post the gradle imports for support libraries. Also these are deprecated too perhaps you should consider migrating to androidx

Comment: Yes you are right I have migrating to androidx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've migrated to androidx and those imports are for the old support libraries you should use newer ones instead. Remove those with these:

```
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog; 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Try if these solve your issue.

For a more complete list of from your current mappings of the old support library packages to the new androidx packages, you can refer the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings).

Comment: Thx ljk its works. but how do we know the list of newer library against replacement of old library

Comment: You can use [this official doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings).

Comment: lots thanks, here I am accept your answer of my question.

Comment: Great I'll add this link to the answer, incase someone else stumbles on this.